# Cocos 2d x not generating libcoco2d.vcxproj or libspine.vcxproj

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, visual-studio-2015

My config:
Windows 10, python 2.7, Visual Studio 2015 community

I downloaded cocos, I successfully run setup.py

Then I proceed to execute "cocos new -l cpp -p com.whatever.Test -d D:\Projects\Cocos\Test".
Everything seems to run ok, no error message whatsoever. If I go to my folder, I can see all the project folders etc. 
I open the sln file within Win32 and it opens the project in visual studio 2015.

Here comes the problem: the solution has 6 projects. 2 of them are not loading and, as a consequence, the main project fails. The failing projects are libcocos2d and libspine. There are no project files generated in their respective folders, so VS can't find the required libcoco2d.vcxproj or libspine.vcxproj.

I'm lost here people, I don't have a single clue on what do I have to do to generate both projects.

Any help will be very much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: happy that you got it fixed. you can answer your own question. please answer it as a post, not an edit :)

Comment: If you've solved your problem, post  your solution as an answer. (Answering  your own question is perfectly valid.) Unlike some other sites, we don't add "SOLVED" to the question title to indicate it's been solved; the way to do that is to accept an answer. I've edited your title, but left your added answer in place so you can repost it as an answer. Please re-edit the question once you've done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. The cocos.py script, at some point, calls CMake. I downloaded CMake and I built the projects using that. It failed. Then I realized that CMake was using the wrong compiler. Even having Visual Studio 2015, the correct compiler is Visual Studio 2014, not Visual Studio 2015 (Thanks a lot M$...). Then CMake was working. After that I tried the script again, and everything is perfect now.